# How to convert a list of IP addresses to a list of address ranges?

Tags: python, ip-address

There are multiple ways to convert a list of IP address to a list of CIDR (netaddr, ipaddr-py).  Is there a way to convert a list of IP address ranges to a merged IP range?

The following examples return a list of tuples of the following format:  `[(start, end)]`.

Example 1:

```
>>> list_of_ips = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2', '192.168.0.3']
>>> print merge_ip_list(list_of_ips)
[('192.168.0.1','192.168.0.3')]
```

Example 2:

```
>>> list_of_ips2 = ['10.0.0.0', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.4']
>>> print merge_ip_list(list_of_ips2)
[('10.0.0.0','10.0.0.0'), ('10.0.0.3','10.0.0.4')]
```

Comment: I am not really sure how to start.  My instinct is telling me this will require recursion.  Take example 1, after combining 192.168.0.1 with 192.168.0.2 `('192.168.0.1','192.168.0.2')`, it will need to combine that resulting range with 192.168.0.3 `('192.168.0.1'-'192.168.0.3')`.

Comment: It could probably be done with recursion, but I'd start by just processing each item in order and check if it's `next` to the previous one...if it is, you keep track, and keep expanding the current range, until it isn't - then you start on the next range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO a good point to start is to make converters from dotted string into int and back. Integer representation is more convenient to compare.

I thought about using reduce but it seems too difficult for me. So I've just implemented it using traditional loop and without recursion.

```
def int2dot( intip ):
    return '.'.join([ str( (intip>>x*8) & 0xFF ) for x in [3,2,1,0]])
def dot2int( dotip ):
    return reduce( lambda r,x: int(x)+(r<<8), dotip.split('.'), 0 )

def merge_ip_list(ip_list):
    if not ip_list:
        return []
    orig = map(dot2int,ip_list)
    orig.sort()
    start = orig[0]
    prev = start-1
    res = []
    for x in orig:
        if x != prev+1:
            res.append((int2dot(start),int2dot(prev)))
            start = x
        prev = x
    res.append((int2dot(start),int2dot(prev)))
    return res
```

Also, I've made an alternative solution:

```
def merge_ip_list_alt(ip_list):
    if not ip_list:
        return []
    orig = sorted(map(dot2int,ip_list))
    end, start = zip(*[x for x in zip(orig,orig[1:]) if x[0]+1!=x[1]]) or ((),())
    start = [int2dot(orig[0])] + map(int2dot,start)
    end = map(int2dot,end) + [int2dot(orig[-1])]
    return zip( start, end )
```

Comment: Try your program with: list_of_ips = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2', '192.168.0.3', '192.168.0.5']

Comment: Hey tyz, thank you for your help.  I do appreciate it as I had no clue on how to even start this.  I do agree that this community values aiding its members, rather than writing complete code.  In fact, I have answered many of my own questions, after being given a push in the right direction.  I'll analyze your code and report back, with hopefully an improved answer.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the missing `('192.168.0.5','192.168.0.5')`.  I will use this code to answer my other [stackoverflow question regarding glob formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915999/python-convert-list-of-ip-cidr-strings-to-a-human-readable-glob).

Comment: This works perfectly.  Even if the elements are not in sequential order.  For example performing merge_ip_list_alt() on `['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2', '192.168.0.3', '192.168.0.5']`, `['192.168.0.5','192.168.0.1','192.168.0.2','192.168.0.3']`, or `['192.168.0.3','192.168.0.1','192.168.0.5','192.168.0.2']` all result in the following correct response:  
`[('192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.3'), ('192.168.0.5', '192.168.0.5')]`.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting if I use a big range, such as 10.35.64.0/20, it should result in `[('10.35.64.0', '10.35.79.255')]`.  `merge_ip_list_alt()` results in following error: `File "<stdin>", line 5, in merge_ip_list_alt` `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`.  `merge_ip_list()` works.  I'm looking into it and will report back.